# JavaScript отладка

Tags: javascript

У меня есть функция на 20.000 строк.
Она принимает 1 строковый параметр.
Мне нужно найти разницу в исполнении при использовании параметров "1" и "2".
Они множество раз копируются и изменяются.
Самый простой способ что я нашел это сравнить авто-сгенерированные комментарии(в chrome или WebStorm)
*Скриншот-пример автосгенерированных коментариев в Chrome(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOfUu.jpg).
И сравнить код с авто-комментариями в Notepad-е.
Но эти комментарии невозможно скопировать.
Как мне лучше справиться с этой задачей.
(брекпоинты и пошаговая отладка не подойдет для 20.000+ строк)
Буду крайне благодарен за любой ответ.

Comment: Жесть какая))))

Comment: `У меня есть функция на 20.000 строк`))

Comment: Мне кажется, вне зависимости от того, какие средства дебагинга у Вас есть, продебажить 20к строк функцию, это крайне истощающий процесс. Разве что каким-то образом, обложить все логами, записать их куда-то, а потом сделать diff этих логов какой-то мердж тулзой, типа araxis merge. Для такого дела скорее всего понадобится покопать в эту тему поглубже, чтобы понять лучше, как сгенерить такие логи, которые можно будет сравнивать нормально. Ну, и вероятно, если нет готового решения, нужно будет написать программку, которая этот самый код логами обкладет)

Comment: Сравнить я планирую с помощью Notepad-a.
Я бы хотел знать как сгенерить такой лог)

Comment: на картинке не автосгенирированные комментарии, это рантайм значения переменных в функции, вам нужны эти данные? или какие? у вижуал код есть отладка `nodejs`, `chrome debugger` но сохранить как файл вы это не сможете

Comment: Две вкладки браузера... запустить и параллельно скроллить, нет?) Если уж необходимая информация уже хоть как-то выводится.

Comment: глянул я этот bwipp ... Думаю для начала можно сделать регулярку, которая возьмет что то вроде `/function\s*(.*?)\((.*?))\s*{/` и добавит к ним console.log("Function $1(...)") (ну или document.write или еще что то выводящее куда нибудь) где вместо многоточия в красивом виде выведет значения всех параметров, которые на вход пришли. Таким образом получите лог вызовов всех внутренних функций с параметрами, от него думаю можно плясать.